# Brute force a ciphered message?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, brute-force-attack

I wrote my own cipher to encrypt messages. I would like to test a sample ciphered message to see how strong it is. Are there any tools for such task either in Windows or Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to verify the strength of a cipher in any automated way, especially given only the ciphertext. Attacking the construction of a cipher is an inherantly intellectual process, which does not fit well to the qualities of computer analysis.

For example, I could write a cipher such that $f(m) = rand(0,n)$ where $n$ is the largest integer representable in $sizeof(m)*8$ bits, and any automated analysis would say "this is an awesome cipher", but a human would immediately realise that it's totally useless.

If you're writing your own ciphers for *real usage*, I have only one piece of advice: **don't**.

Creating your own ciphers is fun, and it can give you a learning experience if you're actually doing it based on constructions you understand, but the resulting cipher should never ever go anywhere near a production system. Experts put their ciphers through years (decades, even) of peer review before they're adopted by anyone. If your goal is to learn, do so by breaking ciphers.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the time to *brute force*, you actually just have to look at the (effective) key space. If there are $k$ different possible keys, and all of them encrypt differently¹, it takes in average about $k/2$ tries to brute-force your cipher. How long this takes then depends on the speed of your cipher (or an optimized version thereof), and the hardware resources of an attacker.

¹<sup>This seems to be trivially the case, but it isn't: While DES uses formally a 64-bit key, 8 of these bits are not used, thus the effective key size is 56 bits, which means that in average $2^{56}/2 = 2^{55}$ tries are enough for brute-force.</sup>

Of course, with home-brewn ciphers usually the best attack is *not* a brute-force attack, but some clever cryptanalysis, which then only needs way less time. These ciphers are then called "broken".